# How to check exact phone number in Java with regex

Tags: java, regex, validation

Hello I am new with regex and i don't have a clue what I am doing. That is why i am seeking for assistance.

I have the following phone number  +359878123456 and i need to check if the phone number matches the criteria.

- +359 is the exact extension
- second 2 numbers are the operator numbers and one of the following 3 numbers: 87,88,89
- next number in the string is a number from 2 to 9
- and the last 6 numbers are any number from 0-9

Additionally i can allow the following numbers in the checking.

- 0878123456 - where  0 changes the value of +359
- 00359878123456 - where 00 changes the value of +

This is where I am at

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ValidatePhoneNumber {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {

      String sPhoneNumber = "+35987";
      //String sPhoneNumber = "605-88899991";
      //String sPhoneNumber = "605-888999A";

      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\+([3][5][9]){[87],[88],[89]}");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sPhoneNumber);

      if (matcher.matches()) {
          System.out.println("Phone Number Valid");
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("Phone Number Not Valid");
      }
 }
}
```

EDITED>

I am checking the numbers are matching that criteria and only print that line.
This is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\+|00)359|0)8[7-9][2-9]\\d{6}$"); //checks evaluation of phone number
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^((\\+|00)359|0)8[7-9][2-9]\\d{6}$");

         File inFile = new File ("phonebook.txt");

          Scanner sc = new Scanner (inFile);
          while (sc.hasNextLine())
          {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            if(line.matches("^((\\+|00)359|0)8[7-9][2-9]\\d{6}$")) // here that code doesn't work
            {
            System.out.println (line);
            }
          }
          sc.close();
        }
```

The file phonebook.txt contains: Name and number

Comment: I know this is not a regex solution but I think that might be better and standard solution for phone number validating: [google's phone number validation and parsing library](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String mob="+359878123456"; 
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^((\\+|00)359|0)(\\-|\\s)?8[7-9][2-9](\\-|\\s)?\\d{3}(\\s|\\-)?\\d{3}$");
    boolean b = p2.matcher("+359-878-123456").matches();
    if(b) System.out.println("True1");

    b = p2.matcher("+359 878 123 456").matches();
    if(b) System.out.println("True2");

    b = p2.matcher("+359-878-123-456").matches();
    if(b) System.out.println("True3");

    b = p2.matcher("+359-878123456").matches();
    if(b) System.out.println("True4");

    b = p2.matcher("00359-878123456").matches();
    if(b) System.out.println("True5");

    b = p2.matcher("0-878-123456").matches();
    if(b) System.out.println("True6");

    b = p2.matcher("+359878123456").matches();
    if(b) System.out.println("True7");

    b = p2.matcher("359878123456").matches(); // without + or 00
    if(b) System.out.println("True8");
    else System.out.println("FALSE8");

    b = p2.matcher("123478123456").matches(); 
    if(b) System.out.println("True9");
    else System.out.println("FALSE9");

  }
}
```

**Updated**

**phonebook.txt**

```js
Sagar +359883123456
Test 00359883123565
Someone 0883123456
People 1234567890  // this will not be printed
Test1 +359873123456
```

**Sample.java**

```js
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Sample{
public static void main(String[] args){
  try{
          File inFile = new File ("phonebook.txt");

          Scanner sc = new Scanner (inFile);
          while (sc.hasNextLine())
          {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            if(line.matches("^((.)*\\s)?((\\+|00)359|0)8[7-9][2-9]\\d{6}$")) // here that code doesn't work
            {
            System.out.println (line);
            }
          }
          sc.close();
}catch(Exception e){}
        }
}
```

**Result**

```js
C:\Users\acer\Desktop\Java\programs>javac Sample.java

C:\Users\acer\Desktop\Java\programs>java Sample
Sagar +359883123456
Test 00359883123565
Someone 0883123456
Test1 +359873123456
```

Comment: Thanks Sugar V this solution is perfect. Tested it with every possible number.

Comment: @DarkoTodorovski I edited the code. Now you can use numbers in other format too like
0 878 123456
+359-878-123456
00359-878-123-456
etc.

Comment: @Sugar V what if I want to have something to be checked out in the following format : Darko Todorovski 0878123456 . Only to check the number in the line. Can you assist me with this?

Comment: It can also be done in the same pattern. Just try it out.

Comment: @Sugar V somehow it doesn't work. I am getting a lane from a txt file and the first line is Darko 0878123456 and i am checking if only the number matches the regex and i print that line. This for me doesn't work somehow :( I will edit the code above.

Comment: Test with `p2` instead of `p`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135783/discussion-between-sagar-v-and-darko-todorovski).

Comment: @DarkoTodorovski Check the updated answer. I think it will clear your problem.

Comment: thanks this works fine. I got one more question to ask. What If i want to change the output of the line with standard output.
Lets say i have the following line: Darko Todorovski 00359878123456 and i want to standardize all numbers, just the numbers with something like this +359 87 8 123456. I know i need to change this line of code
System.out.println (line); with something like this System.out.println(String.valueOf(inputLine).replace(".(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", "($1)-$2-$3")); . But i am really bad with regex :(

Answer (score 4):

Try this regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(((\\+|00)359)|0)8[7-9][2-9][0-9]{6}$");
```

Demo at [ideone](http://ideone.com/v1NL9r).

Comment: Hi Sudo,

Thanks for your fast reply but this regex gives Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: Where does it give it

Comment: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: But `+` is a special char, it must be escaped

Comment: yea I know but I am not able to compile it with this Invalid escape sequence :(

Comment: Instead of \+   use [+]   and then it will work in Java

Comment: I fixed (I used `\\+`). Now it works ([ideone](http://ideone.com/v1NL9r)) - see updated answer.

Comment: Sudo I found the answer from Sugar V thanks for your assistance, It was highly appreciated =)
Your solution works as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add 6 numbers between 0-9 some thing like this

```
    public static void main(String ...args){
      String phoneNumber="+359878123456";

      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\+|0|00)3598[789][2-9][0-9]{6}");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phoneNumber);
      System.out.println(matcher.matches());
}
```

Comment: `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` can be replaced with `[0-9]{6}`

Comment: Thanks Urag for the fast reply. Your solution is good,but this works just for the exact number. What if i change the number with 0878123456 or 00359878123456. It says that the number is invalid which means that it doesn't do the following.

Additionally i can allow the following numbers in the checking.

0878123456 - where 0 changes the value of +359
00359878123456 - where 00 changes the value of +

Comment: Sorry my mistake you are right but how about this pattern "^(\\+|0|00)3598[789][2-9][0-9]{6}"

Comment: Ugar I found the answer from Sugar V thanks for your assistance, It was highly appreciated !