# how to format string line that contains numbers with regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to format telephone numbers from the following format:

- 359878123456
- 0878123456
- 00359878123456

that are placed in a file that has information about name and phone number in the following format:

- DarkoT 00359878123456

to be formatted in a standard form just for the numbers(to ignore the name). see below:

- DarkoT +359 87 2 123456

this is for all cases.

This is where i am at.(my regex)

```
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(inputLine).replaceAll("((\\+|00)359|0)(\\-|\\s)?8[7-9][2-9](\\-|\\s)?\\d{3}(\\s|\\-)?\\d{3}$", "($1)-\\$"));
```

I am confused with the placement. Please advise.

Comment: You must capture the digits, not the delimiters.

Comment: Try `.replaceAll("^((?:\\+|00)?359|0)[-\\s]?(8[7-9][2-9])[-\\s]?(\\d{3})[-\\s]?(\\d{3})$", "$1 $2 $3 $4").replaceFirst("^00", "+")`. See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/g17Sfe).

Comment: See https://ideone.com/g17Sfe.

Comment: You should take a look at [libphonenumber (from google)](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

Comment: Also note that you probably meant `DarkoT +359`

Comment: When i try .replaceAll("^((?:\\+|00)?359|0)[-\\s]?(8[7-9][2-9])[-\\s]?(‌​\\d{3})[-\\s]?(\\d{3‌​})$", "$1 $2 $3 $4").replaceFirst("^00", "+") . I get an error saying some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp1252"

Comment: Additionally this only see the example +359878123456 what about the 0878123456 or 00359878123456 to be normalized in the following format.
+xxx xx x xxxxxx where x are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

1 solution without regex: you could just split the string and group it from the back. But, I would really prefer doing it with regex, so here I go:

I suppose you must have this format (if this is not correct, this will not work):

1. **[OPTIONAL]** 00 (length: 2)
2. **[OPTIONAL]** 111 (Considering always 3 numbers) (length: 3)
3. If you don't have the former: 0 (changing zones, I understand?) (length: 1)
4. 22 (length: 2)
5. 3 (length: 1)
6. 444444 (length: 6)

And now the regex to capture this:

```
(?:(?:00)?(\d{3})|0)(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{6})
```

You will have, as a result:

- Group 1: 3 digits (country code?) or nothing (if it's the '0').
- Group 2: 2 digits (zone?)
- Group 3: 1 digit (no idea, in my country we don't use this)
- Group 4: last 6 digits

Using a replace have some limitations, so I would use a matcher, as easy as:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(originalNumber);
if (m.find()) {
    String nationalCode = m.group(1) != null ? m.group(1) : DEFAULT_NATIONAL_CODE;
    formattedNumber = "+" + nationalCode + " " + m.group(2) + " " + m.group(3) + " " + m.group(4);
}
```

If you want more flexibility (for example, country numbers as 2 digits, not only 3) let me know and I will change the regexp.

**NOTE:** I didn't test this, just coded off the top of my head, let me know if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a continuation of your previous problem [How to check exact phone number in Java with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247918/how-to-check-exact-phone-number-in-java-with-regex/42248375#42248375)

**Sample.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Sample{
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
          File inFile = new File ("phonebook.txt");

          Scanner sc = new Scanner (inFile);
          while (sc.hasNextLine())
          {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            if(line.matches("^((.)*\\s)?((\\+|00)359|0)8[7-9][2-9]\\d{6}$")) // here that code doesn't work
            {
            System.out.println (line.replaceAll("^([^\\s\\+]*\\s?)?((\\+|00)?359|0)[-\\s]?(8[7-9][2-9])[-\\s]?(\\d{3})[-\\s]?(\\d{3})$", "$1 - $2 $4 $5 $6").replaceAll("00359","+359").replaceAll("- 0","+359"));
            }
          }
          sc.close();
}catch(Exception e){}
        }
}
```

**phonebook.txt**

```
Sagar +359883123456
Test 00359883123565
Someone 0883123456
People 1234567890
Test1 +359873123456
```

**Output**

```css
C:\Users\acer\Desktop\Java\programs>javac Sample.java

C:\Users\acer\Desktop\Java\programs>java Sample
Sagar  - +359 883 123 456
Test  - +359 883 123 565
Someone  +359 883 123 456
Test1  - +359 873 123 456
```

Comment: your **java** code is not a *jave-script** that you put it in the **run script** tag